# Best way to get HTML tables side by side to stack for responsive code?

Tags: html, css

I have two table data cells that are side by side which I would like to stack once a media query is fired at 480px. Right now, the tables are responsive but the "display:block" portion doesn't seem to be working once the media query is triggered. I have a "block_td" class assigned to the table data cells which they are inheriting, but I'm not sure why they are not stacking still. Is there something small I'm missing?

It's the portion that reads "This is our first table!" and "This is our second table!".

```
<html lang="en">
<head><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW"><META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX, NOFOLLOW">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title></title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
<style type="text/css">

    table[class=tblPreHeaderLinks] {
        width: 100% !important;
        height: 25px !important;
        clear: both !important;
        float: none !important;
    }

    /* CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES */
    #outlook a{padding:0;} /* Force Outlook to provide a "view in browser" message */
    .ReadMsgBody{width:100%;} .ExternalClass{width:100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display emails at full width */
    .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div {line-height: 100%;} /* Force Hotmail to display normal line spacing */
    body, table, td, a{-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%; -ms-text-size-adjust:100%;} /* Prevent WebKit and Windows mobile changing default text sizes */
    table, td{mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;} /* Remove spacing between tables in Outlook 2007 and up */
    img{-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;} /* Allow smoother rendering of resized image in Internet Explorer */

    /* RESET STYLES */
    body{margin:0; padding:0;}
    img{border:0; height:auto; line-height:100%; outline:none; text-decoration:none;}
    table{border-collapse:collapse !important;}
    body{height:100% !important; margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important;}

    /* iOS BLUE LINKS */
    .appleBody a {color:#68440a; text-decoration: none;} 
    .appleFooter a {color:#999999; text-decoration: none;} 

    /* MOBILE STYLES */

    @media screen and (max-width: 480px) {

        body[yahoo] .block_td {display: block;}


        body {
                -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
                -ms-text-size-adjust: 100%;
            }




        div[class="mobilecontent"]{
        display: block !important;
        max-height: none !important;
        }

        span[class=swMedallion] {
            display:block;
            background-image: url('http://image.email-libertymutual.com/lib/fe6a15707464047f7c1c/m/1/Medallion.jpg') !important;
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
            background-position: center top!important;
            background-size: 100px 96px !important;
            padding-right: 0px !important;
            padding-bottom: 15px !important;
            width:  100px !important;
            height: 96px !important;
        }
        img[class=imgMedallion] {
            display: none !important
            }

            img[class=imgLogo] {
            width: 190px !important;
            height: 76px !important;
        }



        td[class=tdLMLogo] {
        padding: 0 0 0 0 !important;
        }


        /* ALLOWS FOR FLUID TABLES */
        table[class="wrapper"]{
          width:100% !important;
        }

        /* USE THESE CLASSES TO HIDE CONTENT ON MOBILE */
        td[class="mobile-hide"]{
          display:none;}

        img[class="mobile-hide"]{
          display: none !important;
        }

        img[class="img-max"]{
          max-width: 100% !important;
          width: 100% !important;
          height:auto !important;
        }

        a.learnMore {
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
        }

        /* UTILITY CLASSES FOR ADJUSTING PADDING ON MOBILE */

        td[class="section-padding"]{
          padding: 10px 15px 5px 15px !important;
        }

         /* FULL-WIDTH TABLES */
        table[class="responsive-table"]{
          width:100%!important;
        }

        td[class=tdHeaderLinks] {
            font-size: 13px !important;
            line-height: 17px !important;
        }

        td[class=policyNumber] {
            font-size: 9px !important;
            line-height: 13px !important;
        }


    }


</style>
</head>
<body yahoo="fix" style="margin: 0; padding: 0;" bgcolor="#f6f4f5">
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<tbody><tr>
<td align="center">

<!--CONTAINER-->
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#ffffff" >
<tbody><tr>
<td>

    <!--HEADER IMAGES-->
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td style="padding: 0px 15px 5px 15px;" align="center">

            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td width="50%" valign="bottom" class="mobile-hide" class="tdLMLogo" align="left">
                <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@urlLMCOM)=%%" target="_blank">
                    <img src="http://image.email-libertymutual.com/lib/fe6a15707464047f7c1c/m/1/Transactional-LMI-Logo-200x51.jpg" border="0" height="51" width="200" style="display:block" />
                </a>
            </td>  
            <td width="50%" align="left" valign="bottom">
                <!--[if !mso 9]><!-->
                <div class="mobilecontent" style="mso-hide:all;display:none;max-height:0px;overflow:hidden;" align="left">
                    <a href="#" target="_blank">
                        <img src="http://image.email-libertymutual.com/lib/fe6a15707464047f7c1c/m/1/CatAuto-LMI-Logo-155x39.jpg" border="0" height="39" width="155" style="display:block"  />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </td>  <!-- tdLMLogo -->
            <td width="50%" align="right" class="tdMedallion">
                <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@urlMedallion)=%%" target="_blank">
                    <span class="swMedallion">
                        <img src="http://image.email-libertymutual.com/lib/fe6a15707464047f7c1c/m/1/Transactional-Medallion-128x130.jpg" alt="" border="0" width="128" height="130" class="imgMedallion" />
                    </span>
                </a>
            </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody></table>

        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table><!--END OF HEADER IMAGES-->


    <!--LM/MY ACCOUNT/POLICY #-->
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td style="padding: 15px 15px 5px 15px;" align="center">

            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" font="Arial" style="text-align: right; padding-bottom: 15px; font-family : Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:17px; color:#616265; line-height:21px" class="tdHeaderLinks">
                    <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@urlLMCOM)=%%" target="_blank" style="color:#616265"><strong style="color: #616265; font-weight:normal">LibertyMutual.com</strong></a>  |  
                    <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@urlMyAccount)=%%" target="_blank" style="color:#616265"><strong style="color: #616265; font-weight:normal">My Account</strong></a>
                </td>   
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="left" class="policyNumber" style="text-align: right; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height: 17px; color: #616265;">
                    <strong>Policy Number:</strong> %%POLICY_NUMBER%%</span>

                </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table><!--END OF LM/MY ACCOUNT/POLICY #-->

    <!--HELLO CTA-->
    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td style="padding: 15px 15px 5px 15px;" align="center">

            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 22px; line-height: 26px; color:#002663;font-weight:bold;">
                    Hello %%First Name%%,
                    <br />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 20px; color:#616265;padding-top:10px; padding-right:100px;">
                    Your area is likely to receive severe storms in the upcoming months. We've prepared information and tips to help protect you and your loved ones this season.

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding-top:10px;">
                    <a href="#"><img src="http://image.email-libertymutual.com/lib/fe6a15707464047f7c1c/m/1/CatAuto-Button-Learn-More-139x38.jpg" /></a>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="padding: 15px 0px 5px 0px;" class="tdLine">
                    <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tblLine">
                        <tr>
                            <td style="line-height:1px; font-size:1px; background-color:#f6f4f5" class="tdLineActual">&nbsp;</td>
                        </tr>                       
                    </table> <!-- tblLine -->
                </td> <!-- tdLine -->
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top" style="text-align:justify; font-family: Ariel, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 20px; line-height: 24px; color:#002663; padding: 15px 15px 5px 0px;" >
                    <strong>If you need anything this season, we’re here to help 24/7.</strong>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="580" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#ffffff" align="center">
                        <tbody><tr>
                            <td style="padding: 15px 15px 5px 0px;">
                                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                                <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" style="padding:0px 35px 25px 0px;">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td valign="top" width="60" style="padding-right: 10px" >
                                                    <a href="https://www.libertymutual.com/claims-insurance?MM_webID=%%WebID%%" target="_blank"><img src="http://image.email-libertymutual.com/lib/fe6a15707464047f7c1c/m/1/CatAuto-Icon-24-7-50x50.jpg" alt="" border="0"></a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td valign="top" align="left">
                                                    <a href="https://www.libertymutual.com/claims-insurance?MM_webID=%%WebID%%" target="_blank" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#002163; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none; font-size:15px; line-height:19px;">24-Hour Claims Assistance</a>
                                                    <br />
                                                    <span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; line-height:18px;">Easily file claims online, through our app, or by calling 1-800-2Claims.</span>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>

                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" style="padding:0px 35px 25px 0px;">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td valign="top" width="60" style="padding-right: 10px">
                                                    <a href="https://www.libertymutual.com/auto-insurance/auto-insurance-benefits/auto-guaranteed-repairs?MM_webID=%%WebID%%" target="_blank"><img src="http://image.email-libertymutual.com/lib/fe6a15707464047f7c1c/m/1/CatAuto-Icon-Tow-50x50.jpg" alt="" border="0"></a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td valign="top" align="left" >
                                                    <a href="https://www.libertymutual.com/auto-insurance/auto-insurance-benefits/auto-guaranteed-repairs?MM_webID=%%WebID%%" target="_blank" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#002163; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none; font-size:15px; line-height:19px;">Guaranteed Repair Network</a>
                                                    <br />
                                                    <span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; line-height:18px;">2,000+ quality repair shops that are vetted first-hand by Liberty Mutual.</span><sup style="font-size: 8px;">1</sup>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>                       
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" style="padding:0px 35px 15px 0px;">
                                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                                            <tr>
                                                <td valign="top" width="60" style="padding-right: 10px">
                                                    <a href="https://www.libertymutual.com/auto-insurance/understanding-auto-coverages/better-car-replacement?MM_webID=%%WebID%%" target="_blank"><img src="http://image.email-libertymutual.com/lib/fe6a15707464047f7c1c/m/1/CatAuto-Icon-Better-Car-50x50.jpg" alt="" border="0"></a>
                                                </td>
                                                <td valign="top" align="left">
                                                    <a href="https://www.libertymutual.com/auto-insurance/understanding-auto-coverages/better-car-replacement?MM_webID=%%WebID%%" target="_blank" style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; color:#002163; font-weight:bold; text-decoration:none; font-size:15px; line-height:19px;">Better Car Replacement</a>
                                                    <br />
                                                    <span style="font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:14px; color:#333333; line-height:18px;">Trapped in high water or concerned about falling trees? We’ll replace your car with something newer.</span><sup style="font-size: 8px;">2</sup>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        </table>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                                </tbody></table>
                            </td>
                        </tr>


                        </tbody></table>
                    </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody></table>

        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody></table>





     <!--BOTTOM CONTAINER-->

     <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="610" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#f6f4f5">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td align="center">

                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin-top:10px">
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                <td>
                    <TABLE BORDER="1" WIDTH="610" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="wrapper">
                      <TR>
                       <TD WIDTH="290" align="left" class="block_td">
                        <TABLE BORDER="1"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                         <TR>
                          <TD>
                           This is in our first table!
                          </TD>
                         </TR>
                        </TABLE>
                       </TD>
                       <TD WIDTH="290" align="left" class="block_td">
                        <TABLE BORDER="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#ffffff">
                         <TR>
                          <TD >
                           And this is in the second table!
                          </TD>
                         </TR>
                        </TABLE>
                       </TD>
                      </TR>
                    </TABLE>
                </td>

                </tr>

                </tbody></table>

            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table> <!--END OF BOTTOM CONTAINER-->

</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td style="padding-top: 10px;" class="tdLine" bgcolor="#f6f4f5">
        <table width="100%" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="tblLine">
            <tr>
                <td style="line-height:10px; font-size:10px; background-color:#ecad00" class="tdLineActual">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>                       
        </table> <!-- tblLine -->
    </td> <!-- tdLine -->
</tr>

<tr>
<td bgcolor="#f6f4f5">

<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="610" class="wrapper" bgcolor="#f6f4f5" align="center">
                            <tbody><tr>
                                        <td align="center" style="padding-top:20px;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#616265; height: 16px;" class="tdConnect">
                                            Connect with us:
                                        </td> <!--tdConnect -->
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td class="tdSocial" style="padding-bottom: 15px" align="center">
                                            <table cellpadding="0" width="100" class="tblSocial">
                                                <tbody><tr>
                                                    <td class="tdFB" style="padding: 0 5px 0 5px; width: 25%;" align="center">
                                                        <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@facebook)=%%" target="_blank">
                                                            <img src="http://image.email-libertymutual.com/lib/ffcf14/m/1/social_default_facebook_icon.jpg" height="20" width="20" border="0" alt="Facebook" class="imgFB">
                                                        </a>
                                                    </td> <!-- tdFB -->
                                                    <td class="tdTW" style="padding: 0 5px 0 5px" align="center">
                                                        <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@twitter)=%%" target="_blank">
                                                            <img src="http://image.email-libertymutual.com/lib/ffcf14/m/1/social_default_twitter_icon.jpg" height="20" width="20" border="0" alt="Twitter" class="imgTW">
                                                        </a>
                                                    </td> <!-- tdTW -->
                                                    <td class="tdIG" style="padding: 0 5px 0 5px" align="center">
                                                        <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@instagram)=%%" target="_blank">
                                                            <img src="http://image.email-libertymutual.com/lib/fe6a15707464047f7c1c/m/1/social_default_instagram_icon.jpg" height="20" width="20" border="0" alt="Instagram" class="imgIG">
                                                        </a>
                                                    </td> <!-- tdIG -->
                                                    <td class="tdYT" style="padding: 0 5px 0 5px" align="center">
                                                        <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@youtube)=%%" target="_blank">
                                                            <img src="http://image.email-libertymutual.com/lib/fe6a15707464047f7c1c/m/1/social_default_youtube_icon.jpg" height="20" width="20" border="0" alt="YouTube" class="imgYT">
                                                        </a>
                                                    </td> <!-- tdYT -->
                                                </tr>
                                            </tbody></table> <!--tblSocial -->
                                        </td> <!-- tdSocial -->
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#616265; font-weight:bold; line-height:18px" class="tdQuestions">
                                            Questions?
                                        </td> <!-- tdQuestions -->
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#616265; line-height:18px; padding-bottom:15px" class="tdContact">
                                            <a href="https://www.libertymutual.com/customer-service/contact-us?MM_webID=%%WebID%%" target="_blank" style="color:#616265">
                                                <strong style="color: #616265; font-weight:normal">Contact Us,</strong></a> Tweet us 
                                            <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@twitterAsk)=%%" target="_blank" style="color:#616265"><strong style="color: #616265; font-weight:normal">@AskLiberty</strong></a>,
                                            or Ask us on <a href="%%=RedirectTo(@twitterAsk)=%%" target="_blank" style="color:#616265"><strong style="color: #616265; font-weight:normal">Facebook</strong></a>
                                        </td> <!-- tdContact -->
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#616265; font-weight:bold; line-height:18px" class="tdMngTitle">
                                            Manage your policy online:
                                        </td> <!-- tdMngTitle -->
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:13px; color:#616265; line-height:18px; padding-bottom:15px" class="tdRegister">
                                            <a href="https://eservice.libertymutual.com/PmInternetContentserviceWeb/insurance/url?uri=home?&MM_webID=%%WebID%%" target="_blank" style="color:#616265"><strong style="color: #616265; font-weight:normal">My Account</strong></a>
                                            or 
                                            <a href="https://eservice.libertymutual.com/PmInternetContentserviceWeb/url?uri=register&MM_webID=%%WebID%%" target="_blank" style="color:#626265"><strong style="color: #616265; font-weight:normal">Register</strong></a>
                                        </td> <!-- tdRegister -->
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; color:#616265; line-height:15px; padding:0 30px 15px 30px" class="tdDisclaimer">
                                            <sup>1</sup>The property damage must be covered by your policy. Guaranteed Repair Network not available in Rhode Island or Massachusetts. In Massachusetts we offer you our Superior Service Program, which is similar to the Guaranteed Repair Network, however, the estimate is completed by a Liberty Mutual appraiser. For more information, speak with your Liberty Mutual Claims Representative.
                                        </td> <!--tdDisclaimer -->
                                    </tr>


                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; color:#616265; line-height:15px; padding:0 30px 15px 30px" class="tdDisclaimer">
                                            <sup>2</sup>Optional coverage. Applies to a covered total loss. Deductible applies. Does not apply to leased vehicles and motorcycles. Not available in NC.
                                        </td> <!--tdDisclaimer -->
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; color:#616265; line-height:15px; padding:0 30px 15px 30px" class="tdDisclaimer">
                                            Liberty Mutual Insurance is licensed in all 50 states and the District of Columbia.
                                        </td> <!--tdDisclaimer -->
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; color:#616265; line-height:15px; padding:0 30px 15px 30px" class="tdLegalese">
                                            This email was sent to <a href="mailto:%%email address%%" style="color:#616265; text-decoration:none" class="grayLinkNoUL">%%email address%%</a>. If you do not wish to receive email messages from Liberty&nbsp;Mutual that are advertising or promotional in 
                                            nature, please 
                                            <a href="%%unsub_center_url%%" alias="Unsubscribe" style="color:#616265"><strong style="color: #616265; font-weight:normal">unsubscribe</strong></a> now. If you would like to modify your profile, 
                                            <a href="%%profile_center_url%%" alias="Update Profile" style="color:#616265"><strong style="color: #616265; font-weight:normal">go here.</strong></a><br><br>
                                            ©%%=v(@copyDate)=%% %%Member_Busname%% <a class="grayLinkNoUL" style="text-decoration:none; color:#616265">%%Member_Addr%%, %%Member_City%%, %%Member_State%%, %%Member_PostalCode%%</a>.
                                        </td> <!-- tdLegalese -->
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:10px; color:#616265; line-height:15px; padding-bottom:15px; height: 28px;" class="tdAbout">
                                            <a href="http://www.libertymutualgroup.com/omapps/ContentServer?pagename=LMGroup/Views/LMG&MM_webID=%%WebID%%" target="_blank" style="color:#616265">
                                                <strong style="color: #616265; font-weight:normal">About Liberty Mutual</strong></a> | 
                                            <a href="http://www.libertymutualgroup.com/omapps/ContentServer?pagename=LMGroup/Views/lmgDisclosure&cid=1138362980102" target="_blank" style="color:#616265">
                                                <strong style="color: #616265; font-weight:normal">Privacy Policy</strong></a>
                                        </td> <!-- tdAbout -->
                                    </tr>
                                </table>

</td>
</tr>


</tbody></table><!---END OF CONTAINER-->    

</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I pasted all of your code into a jsfiddle and it stacks just fine:
http://jsfiddle.net/eh9748yy/

Comment: Is this a newsletter?

Comment: Hello, yes it's newsletter. This is what I get when I resize my window: http://i.imgur.com/V4rX2zK.jpg. It's supposed to have the "This is our second table!" below the "This is our first table." When I resize it to a 480px window with dreamweaver. I get the above result as well.

Comment: Please specify which browser or email client is this. Create cross client responsive email is really hard.

Comment: I'm currently viewing it in Chrome and Firefox. I also tried viewing on iPhone IOS.

Comment: I'd really like the two tables to stack just by re-sizing my browser.

Comment: You should really try to reduce your problem to just the relevant portion of CSS and HTML.

Comment: Is this still an issue?